# Disable pylint execution on a section of code or function

Tags: python, skip, pylint

I am using pylint 0.27 with python 2.7.3. Pylint has a known bug which hits when it analyses code having a `.next()` call. As given in http://www.logilab.org/122793 link, it fails with the given traceback.

**I cannot change my python and pylint versions** but I would like to workaround this problem by disabling pylint on the piece of code that has `.next()` call by adding a `#pylint: MAGIC` comment in my code.

I could find support for disabling pylint checking on a file using `#pylint: skip-file` but I am interested at doing this at function level or rather at line level.

Any other workarounds are also welcomed!

Answer (score 20):

You can accomplish this by adding the pylint comment as the first line of the function body like so:

```
def wont_raise_pylint():
  # pylint: disable=W0212
  some_module._protected_member()
  some_module._protected_member()

def will_still_raise_pylint():
  some_module._protected_member()
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable pylint entirely for a function **without needing to enumerate each pylint violation code**, specify `all` to the disable, eg:

```py
def foo():
    # pylint: disable=all
    """You put the disable right under the function signature 
    to disable pylint for the entire function scope.
    """
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

When I refactor code, I wrap the portion I have yet to touch
in a `class ToDo` and start that class with a directive
to ignore all messages. At the end of the class the directive
goes out of scope. MWE:

```py
def unused_variable(foo=''):
    "generate W0613"

class ToDo:
    #pylint: disable = E, W, R, C
    #disables W0613 and E0213

    def unused_variable(foo=''):
        "generate W0613 and E0213"

def main(foo=''):
    "generate W0613"
```

Comment: I was getting pylint-error for nested lambda in Python 2.7 (Pylint throws up an error for this and this in Python-2 is not supported any more); `#pylint: disable = E, W, R, C` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly you won't be able to locally avoid the error you encounter.

One could expect to locate in the source code the offending piece of code, and then locally disable the involved message(s), but this won't work because it will still be run. This is because when locally disabling a message, the code detecting this message is run, only the message isn't be emitted in the end.

However, it *may* work if you globally disable this message (depending on the way it's implemented). In your case it seems unfortunatly that you would have to skip the whole 'logging' checker.

To sum up, to avoid your traceback you may either:

- locally use `pylint: skip-file`, in which case every pylint's features will be activated but the whole offending file will be skipped
- globally disable the 'logging' checker (`--disable=logging`), in which case the whole code (including the offending file) will be checked but without the 'logging' checker messages